# How to proceed when passing a Record vs Passing a class to a procedure

Tags: pascal, delphi

Lets say i have a class called TProgramSettings which looks like this:

```
TProgramSettings = class
   flags: UInt32;
   ...
end;

PProgramSettings = ^TProgramSettings;
```

So I initialize my program like this:

```
var
  MyProgramSettings: TProgramSettings;
begin
  MyProgramSettings := TProgramSettings.Create;
  MyProgramSettings.Flags := 0;
  ApplySettings(@MyProgramSettings);
```

And the procedure ApplySettings looks like this:

```
procedure ApplySettings(ProgramSettings: PProgramSettings);
var
  MyObject : TCustomObject;
begin
  MyObject := TCustomObject.Create;
  MyObject.Settings.Flags := ProgramSettings^.Flags;
  ...
end;
```

Right now my code looks like this, however I wonder if there is any better way to do it? Am I breaking Object Pascal/Delphi code conventions? Would it be better to just make TProgramSettings a record? I really dont understand the difference between Records and Classes, all I know  is that classes must be initialized. In the case I make TProgramSettings a record from what I've read I shouldn't pass a pointer to it since the record points to the same addres in memory and doesn't need to be referenced like the class. How should I go about it? Any help would be aprreciated  :)

Comment: Class instance variables are pointers. So you need to drop the pointer declaration and pass MyProgramSettings itself around. For passing a reference see [var](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Value_and_Variable_Parameters) parameters. Read the documentation to have a better understanding of [classes](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Classes_and_Objects_(Delphi)) and [records](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)).

Comment: ^^^^^ this ^^^^^

Comment: Also, have you considered that `ApplySettings` could simply be a method of the class?

Comment: Be sure to Free the class instance when you are done using it.

Answer (score 2):

An object of type class is already a pointer, so there really is no need to dereference it as you do. The equivalent is

```
TProgramSettings = class
   flags: UInt32;
   ...
end;
```

…

```
var
  MyProgramSettings: TProgramSettings;
begin
  MyProgramSettings := TProgramSettings.Create;
  MyProgramSettings.Flags := 0;
  ApplySettings(MyProgramSettings);
```

…

```
procedure ApplySettings(ProgramSettings: TProgramSettings);
var
  MyObject : TCustomObject;
begin
  MyObject := TCustomObject.Create;
  MyObject.Settings.Flags := ProgramSettings.Flags;
  ...
end;
```

As regards the difference between a record and a class object, well, one way to think of it is that when you define a record as a var, that definition creates the record (no need to call 'Create') whereas for a class you are just creating a point to the object, and you still need to create the object itself. There is a lot more to than that, but it is away to start thinking about it.

Comment: Okay so let me try to understand it, a class is just a pointer to a type. And an instance of a class is just a pointer to some space in memory that contains all the information. On the other hand a record is like a "global variable" and it contains all the information within it, hence it should be passed as a pointer. Is this right?

Comment: It's not about what a class "is".  The point is that Delphi's Object Pascal syntax allows you to bypass dereferencing the instance pointer transparently. just by writing f.i. `MyClass.DoSomething`

Comment: @Gerard: no, a variable of type TProgramSettings is just a pointer to the instance of the class. More in the documentation and a little more here: http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pointers.html#objects

Comment: No. A record isn't a global variable. A record, like a class, is simply a compound type. The key difference between them is that classes are reference types, records are value types. The assignment operator behaves differently because of that. Read documentation or perhaps an beginner's book. Very important you do that.

Comment: Note that "define" <> "declare". You mean "declare" instead of "define". Define is when you describe something like a type, whereas declare is when you actually use one of those.

Comment: @Jerry What is your source for that? Declaring states the existence of something, defining is the act of stating what it is.

Comment: @David Yes, that's exactly my point, in different words. You don't "define" a variable, you "declare" it.

Comment: @Jerry It's not what you said though. For instance you can declare types, with forward declarations. That's not using something that you defined earlier.

Comment: @GerardMarquina *"On the other hand a record is like a "global variable" and it contains all the information within it, hence it should be passed as a pointer. Is this right? "* A record is not a global variable. As to passing by value, there are better ways of doing that than dereferencing. For example if **TProgramSettings** were a record you could define Apply settings as **procedure ApplySettings(var ProgramSettings: TProgramSettings);**